# Is it possible to compile files which are changed due to compiler preprocessor macros in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macros

I have a project which I need to compile with different preprocessor macros. To reduce the compile time, I would like to compile only the files which re changed due to the macros and then somehow put them in the app binary. Is it possible to do using Xcode or command line tools for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

If the macros are defined in a header file, it might only recompile files that #import or #include that header. Make sure to import the header only in source files where the macros are used to limit the recompiles.

If the macros are defined in the project file, imported or defined in a prefix file or added from the command-line, then it will likely recompile the whole project as it can't tell who depends on them.  (Unless some newer version of Xcode can analyze and adapt for that.)